# UIViews are blank when added to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to add the Views of a ViewControllerClass to a ScrollView.

The problem is that only the first page is showing up, the other ones are blank.

This is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    [imageArray2 addObject:[[WeatherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WeatherViewController" picname:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"s%@.png", [[xmlParser.weatherdata.timedata objectAtIndex:i] iconSymbol]] degree:@"0°" weathertimedata:[xmlParser.weatherdata.timedata objectAtIndex:i] town:[xmlParser.weatherdata town]]];
}

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 8, scrollView.frame.size.height);

for(WeatherViewController *iv in imageArray2)
{
    [self.scrollView addSubview:iv.view];
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: are u setting frame of those views properly...there is a chance where these views might be overlapping on each other..

Comment: Have you set frae of scrollView properly before for loop

Comment: All your WeatherViewControllers have the same frame, so you are adding all view on the same point.
You have to modify the frame of every WeatherViewController dinamically and them add them

Comment: You haven't set the views frames that's why only first view is showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign your calculate frame to your `WeatherViewController`'s view on your loop.

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    WeatherViewController *myWeatherVC = [[WeatherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WeatherViewController" picname:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"s%@.png", [[xmlParser.weatherdata.timedata objectAtIndex:i] iconSymbol]] degree:@"0°" weathertimedata:[xmlParser.weatherdata.timedata objectAtIndex:i] town:[xmlParser.weatherdata town]]
    myWeatherVC.view.frame = frame;


    [imageArray2 addObject:myWeatherVC];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:myWeatherVC.view];

}
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 8, scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the frame like this and it will work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        WeatherViewController *thisView = [[WeatherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WeatherViewController" picname:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"s%@.png", [[xmlParser.weatherdata.timedata objectAtIndex:i] iconSymbol]] degree:@"0°" weathertimedata:[xmlParser.weatherdata.timedata objectAtIndex:i] town:[xmlParser.weatherdata town]]
        [thisView.view setFrame:frame];
        [imageArray2 addObject:thisView];
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 8, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    for(WeatherViewController *iv in imageArray2)
    {
        [self.scrollView addSubview:iv.view];
    }
```

**Hope this will help you.**